# What can I do to get images resized by passing a width parameter in the request?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, image, compression

I want my compressed images but, I don't want to compress them in upload and I don't want to resize width and height using css or stuff like that.
I want to call an image like:

```
<img src="/images/exaple.png?width200px">
```

and my image that is 2000px x 1000px will be 200px x 100px on my page.

I have only found programs that you have to pay for, and moreover, I don't have a Linux server to install this program on since I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First I make  the width as variable adding the `=`

```
<img src="/images/exaple.png?width=200px">
```

Then you need to handle the static file of the image using asp.net.
Static files like images not pass from asp.net unless you declare it on handlers on `web.config`

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.bmp" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler,ImageHandler"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler,ImageHandler"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.gif" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler,ImageHandler"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.png" type="ImageHandler.HttpImageHandler,ImageHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

And last you need to create the handler

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ImageHandler{
    public class HttpImageHandler: IHttpHandler{
    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;

    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
      if(context.Request.Params["height"] != null){
        try{
           Height = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["height"]);
        }catch{
           Height = 0;
        }
      }

      if(context.Request.Params["width"] != null){
        try{
           Width = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["width"]);
        }catch{
           Width = 0;
        }
      }

      if (Width <= 0 && Height <=0)
      {               
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = 
        getContentType(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        context.Response.End();
      }
      else 
      {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = 
        getContentType(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        byte[] buffer = 
        getResizedImage(context.Request.PhysicalPath,Width,Height);
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write
        (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        context.Response.End();
      }
    }

    public bool IsReusable{
        get{
            return false;
        }
    }

    byte[] getResizedImage(String path ,int width,int height)
    {
        Bitmap imgIn = new Bitmap(path);
        double y  = imgIn.Height;
        double x  = imgIn.Width;

        double factor = 1;
        if(width > 0){
            factor = width/x;
        }else if (height>0){
            factor = height/y;
        }
        System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = 
        new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Bitmap imgOut = 
        new Bitmap((int)(x * factor),(int)(y * factor));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawImage(imgIn,new Rectangle(0,0,(int)(factor * x),
        (int)(factor * y)),
        new Rectangle(0,0,(int)x,(int)y),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        imgOut.Save(outStream, getImageFormat(path));
        return outStream.ToArray();
    }  

    string getContentType(String path){
        switch (Path.GetExtension(path)) {
            case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp";
            case ".gif": return "Image/gif";
            case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg";
            case ".png": return "Image/png";
            default :  break;
        }
        return "";
    }

    ImageFormat getImageFormat(String path){
        switch (Path.GetExtension(path)) {
            case ".bmp": return ImageFormat.Bmp;
            case ".gif": return ImageFormat.Gif;
            case ".jpg": return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            case ".png": return ImageFormat.Png;
            default :  break;
        }
        return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    }
    }
}
```

Reference : [HTTP Handlers for Images in ASP.NET](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent3.aspx)

Other examples : 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/working-with-image-in-httphandler/

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Two-ASP-NET-HttpHandler-Image-Hacks.id-291916.html

Comment: Thank you very much to answer me!
I don't have idea about how create an handler, I have never did it, i was looking for about that on google.
I have to save this file .cs? Where do i have to put it? Thank you

Comment: @MirkoBaldassini You can either create a different dll library connected with your site (put the dll later on bin), but you can also add it on the App_code

Comment: I have downloaded visual studio 2017 and I have put your code but it had a lot of mistakes, maybe cause I didnt config true staff, I tried with the others but the same, Im so neat to the dll but i still dont have, crazy

Comment: @MirkoBaldassini get the code from here : http://www.jigar.net/viewcontent.ashx?contentid=71

Comment: I had problem with this too because it said to me “csc” is unknown.. anyway I corrected the errors on visual studio I just put some references, to System.Web and Drawing and finally I have my compiled file. I put that in the folder bin that I have created and I  have uploaded the web.config like you said to me. I made a simple page html with only a img with the variable like you told me but it doesn’t do nothing. The image is 3000px not 200px of width like I m calling. What s wrong? Thank you very much

Comment: I was seeing that in one of the page that you passed me a guy was talking about to put in web.config and to add manualment in IIS in the window Add/Edit Application Extension Mapping, he said both but, I have IIS10 and it's different, i tried to add in Handler Mapping a Script map but still doesnt do nothing